# How to evaluate the integral in the following cosine Fourier transform?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Could anyone prove the following equation: $$\int^{\infty}_0 e^{-a\sqrt{x}}\cos(a\sqrt{x})\cos(bx)\,dx=a\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{8b^3}}e^{-\frac{a^2}{2b}}$$

Comment: Use complex numbers to go from cosine to an exponential integral. Complete the square to evaluate it or use a https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral

Comment: @b00nheT could you kindly provide some steps? I have tried exponential integral quite some time but failed to get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some first steps:

Let's first do the substitution $\sqrt{x}=u$ so to get an integral without square roots: $dx=2u\,du$
\begin{align}\int^{\infty}_0 e^{-a\sqrt{x}}\cos(a\sqrt{x})\cos(bx)\,dx& =
\int^{\infty}_0 e^{-au}\cos(au)\cos(bu^2)2u\,dx\\&=\int^{\infty}_0 e^{-au}\frac{e^{iau}+e^{-iau}}{2}\frac{e^{ibu^2}+e^{-ibu^2}}{2}\cdot 2u\,du\\&=\text{a sum of terms of the form}\\ & = \int_0^\infty u\ e^{c_1u^2+c_2u+c_3}\, du
\end{align}
where $c_1,c_2,c_3$ are complex numbers.

This integral is equivalent to calculating the first moment of a normal distribution. To evaluate that, we note that 
$$\frac{d}{du}e^{c_1u^2+c_2u+c_3}=(2uc_1+c_2)e^{c_1u^2+c_2u+c_3},$$
and thus (by matching constants accordingly) rewrite the above as
$$\int_0^\infty (2c_1u+c_2)\ e^{c_1u^2+c_2u+c_3}\, du-\int_0^\infty c_2\ e^{c_1u^2+c_2u+c_3}\, du.
$$
The first integrand has a simple primitive. The second can be evaluted directly using the formula for the Gaussian integral

Comment: Thx. I got stuck at the second equation and maybe I will proceed further